# Angularjs plugin 'ngclipboard'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use an angular plugin called ngclipboard (https://sachinchoolur.github.io/ngclipboard/), but I must be doing something wrong as it does not seem to work. I do not have any error messages, but the input from the textbox does not get copied into the clipboard. Please check out this jsfiddle and let me know how I can correct this: https://jsfiddle.net/2cw2zaqa/

```
<input type='text' id='link' value='123' />
<button ngclipboard data-clipboard-target="#link">COPY</button>
```

Thanks,
Tamas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the buttons into a span, indicating the `ng-app`:

```
<span ng-app="ngclipboard">
  <input type='text' id='link' value='123' />
  <button ngclipboard data-clipboard-target="#link">COPY</button>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone will need this in the future, here is a version of the code, that works: https://jsfiddle.net/ocaL36wv/. One of the major fixes was to use an old version of `clipboard.js` by referencing:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/2.0/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
```